# Find total number of months, divide whole number by total number of months

Tags: cognito-forms, calculator

I am trying to calculate the average number of followers my clients have gained in the time they have been on Instagram. I want to take the number of followers and divide it by the number of months they have been on Instagram. This will produce the average number of followers gained per month historically.

I would like to have them set a future goal for growth based on a percentage monthly increase.

Example:

Range (Start Date: Current Date)/30.4 Days = Number of Months

Number of Followers/Number of Months = Average Followers per Month

Average Followers per month * 2 = Projected Goal

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with Cognito Forms. Your calculator can be easily created using our [calculation field](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations). You can also find examples and tips on how to use the calculation field on our [support page](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations). Here are some screenshots of a form I created based on my understanding of your example.

[image]

[image]